# How to read webkitAllowFullScreen attribute in iframe using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

For the following iframe code:

```
<iframe src="testA.html" webkitAllowFullScreen mozallowfullscreen allowFullScreen></iframe>
```

Inside testA.html, how do I tell if the webkitAllowFullScreen attribute is included using javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most robust solution:

```
if(window.frameElement && window.frameElement.hasAttribute("webkitAllowFullScreen")){

}
```

It utilizes [`window.frameElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.frameElement), which returns the DOM node of the parent framing element, which you can then make a [`hasAttribute`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.hasAttribute) call against.

Comment: How does testA.html know it is called testA.html?  I'd rather not hardcode the file name value.

Comment: Ah, well, that's a bit different. This obviously only works on iframes on the same domain (due to the same origin policy), so, the above should work as long as you don't use weird iframe code

Comment: Added more specific clarifications about the `boolean` attribute situation

Comment: That helps.  What if I have multiple <iframe src="testA.html"></iframe> on the parent document and some have the webkitAllowFullScreen attribute and others do not?

Comment: Important question. I went back to the drawing board and realized we don't need a hacky solution. The above is fully robust.

Comment: That seems to work great, except window.frameElement seems to always be undefined in webkit.

Answer (score 5):

If the allowfullscreen attributes are added to the iframe the variable below should be `true`

```
var fullscreenEnabled = document.fullscreenEnabled || document.webkitFullscreenEnabled || document.mozFullScreenEnabled;
```

This even works when the iframe src is on a different domain.
**Note: the letter s in fullscreenEnabled is uppercase for Firefox**